# Is there a way to filter blocks by vocabulary instead of NID or CT?

Tags: blocks

Each time I set the block visibility, I can do it only by node ID or content type.

Is there a way to set the block visibility using a taxonomy term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to "[How to make "Page specific visibility settings" for blocks more flexible?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/how-to-make-page-specific-visibility-settings-for-blocks-more-flexible/194442#194442)". It explains how the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module can be used to answer that question.

Your question here seems to be a variation of it. You could use a similar approach, so that in the end you'd only have to write a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Component related to your criteria here, ie to intercept your condition about "***if at least one term of a given vocabulary is in the node***" (in which case the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module should take care of "***showing the block in whatever region***". Done!

**Note**: for this to work, do not have to enable the PHP Filter module (always a good thing if you can  avoid that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP block visibility setting to return true when the node has any of the terms you want

```
<?php
  if (condition) {
    return TRUE;  // block will be shown
  }
  return FALSE;
?>
```

Edit: You need PHP Filter module enabled for that